# Google script xls attachment not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

any thoughts as to why this script emails an attachment but the attachment is not the correct spreadsheet, and looks like some sort of google error page.

[image]

```js
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
  
  try {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    Logger.log(url);
    
    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };
    
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
    
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@email.com", "Google Sheet to Excel", "The XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});
    
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess API has changed. You can try [Drive REST API(v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) instead. Replace

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
var params = { ... };
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
```

to

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + ss.getId() + 
  "/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&key=" +
  "{your API key}";
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
```

I tested and it worked. Of course you first should get your own API key, etc, at [API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com). Then you can try some APIs like simple GET requests at [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/). Or you can try some APIs, in this case `Files: export`, also at [the documentation page itself](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#try-it), but notice that you cannot try your own API key here.

Comment: I am receiving an error and it is not working for me. [17-03-24 11:51:17:145 CST] Exception: Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/MYFILEIDWASHERE/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&key=APIKEYWASHERE returned code 404. Truncated server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: MYFILEIDWASHERE... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: I figured out the error is due to the sharing of the spreadsheet- If I open it up to the public it works. Is there a way to keep it not open to the public? And still use this feature?

Comment: Sorry I can't find relevant information. **Maybe** you can 1) set the permission to public before exporting, 2) export it, 3) then set the permission to its orginal permission. **I think** 1) and 3) can be done via [Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions). Good luck. :)

Comment: This did work thank you for your help! I will update the code above to reflect your method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the updated code that @sangbok helped with:

```js
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
  
  try {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
    
    // sets sharing to public - to send out email.
    sheet.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + ss.getId() + "/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet&key=" + "YOURAPIKEYGOESHERE4";
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    
    Logger.log(url);
    
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
    
    var now = new Date();
    
    MailApp.sendEmail("YOUREMAILADDRESSGOESHERE", "EMAIL SUBJECT " + now , "EMAIL BODY " + now , {attachments: [blob]});
    
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
    // returns the file back to Private access
    sheet.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

Comment: Glad that you make it! :)